# Forwarding udp ports iptables packets "lost"?

Tags: linux, iptables, udp

I have a Linux router (Debian 6.x) where i forward some ports to internal services.
Some tcp ports (like 80, 22...) are OK.

I have one Application listening on port 54277udp.
No return is coming from this app, i only get Data on this port.

Router:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter = 1
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding = 1
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ppp0/forwarding = 1

$IPTABLES -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp -i ppp0 --dport 54277 -j DNAT --to-destination $SRV_IP:54277
$IPTABLES -I FORWARD -p udp -d $SRV_IP --dport 54277 -j ACCEPT
```

Also MASQUERADING internal traffic to ppp0(internet) is active & working.

Default Policy INPUT&OUTPUT&FORWARD is DROP

What is strange, when i do:

```
tcpdump -p -vvvv -i ppp0 port 54277
```

I get a lot of traffic:

```
18:35:43.646133 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 57)
    source.ip > own.external.ip..54277: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 29
18:35:43.652301 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 57)
    source.ip > own.external.ip..54277: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 29
18:35:43.653324 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 57)
    source.ip > own.external.ip..54277: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 29
18:35:43.655795 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 57)
    source.ip > own.external.ip..54277: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 29
18:35:43.656727 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 57)
    source.ip > own.external.ip..54277: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 29
18:35:43.659719 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 57)
    source.ip > own.external.ip..54277: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 29
```

`tcpdump -p -i eth0 port 54277` (on the same machine, the router)
i get much less traffic.

also on the destination `$SRV_IP` there are only a few packets coming in, but not all.

INTERNAL SERVER:

```
19:15:30.039663 IP source.ip.52394 > 192.168.215.4.54277: UDP, length 16
19:15:30.276112 IP source.ip.52394 > 192.168.215.4.54277: UDP, length 16
19:15:30.726048 IP source.ip.52394 > 192.168.215.4.54277: UDP, length 16
```

So some udp ports are "ignored/dropped" ?

Any idea what could be wrong?

Edit:

This is strange: The Forward rule has data packets, but the PREROUTING rule has 0 packets...

```
iptables -nvL -t filter |grep 54277
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes) 
168  8401 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.215.4       state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED udp dpt:54277

iptables -nvL -t nat |grep 54277
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 405 packets, 24360 bytes) 
0     0 DNAT       udp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            my.external.ip      udp dpt:54277 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED to:192.168.215.4
```

Edit2:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 102K packets, 6148K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0     0 DNAT       udp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            external.ip      udp dpt:54277 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED to:192.168.215.4
1191 71460 DNAT       tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 to:192.168.215.4
3119  187K DNAT       tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 to:192.168.215.3
+some other tcp forward rules

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4626 packets, 294K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
2343  145K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1529 packets, 111K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination



Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
574K   33M PSAD_BLOCK_INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4511K  257M ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:54277
559 30745 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:17784
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       192.168.215.30       0.0.0.0/0
16  3355 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:43 dpts:1024:65535 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:45000
1    40 DROP       all  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           match-set netdrop src
0     0 LOG        all  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           match-set netdrop src LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `IPSET'
403 35523 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 DROP       all  --  ppp0   *       10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0
0     0 DROP       all  --  ppp0   *       172.16.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
0     0 DROP       all  --  ppp0   *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0
0     0 DROP       all  --  ppp0   *       224.0.0.0/4          0.0.0.0/0
0     0 DROP       all  --  ppp0   *       240.0.0.0/5          0.0.0.0/0
0     0 LOG        tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `Drop-Syn'
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW
0     0 LOG        all  -f  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `Fragments-Packets'
0     0 DROP       all  -f  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x29
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
0     0 LOG        tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x00 limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `NULL-Packets'
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
2    96 DROP       tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x06
0     0 LOG        tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x03/0x03 limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `XMAS-Packets'
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x03/0x03
0     0 LOG        tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x11/0x01 limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `Fin-Packets-Scan'
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x11/0x01
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x37
0     0 LOG        all  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           match-set ipdrop src LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `IPSET:'
0     0 DROP       all  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           match-set ipdrop src
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 0 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
1445  121K ACCEPT     icmp --  eth0   *       192.168.215.0/24     192.168.215.254     icmp type 8 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       192.168.215.0/24     192.168.215.254     tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       192.168.215.0/24     192.168.215.254     udp dpt:161 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
1479 94070 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       192.168.215.0/24     192.168.215.254     tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
2220  265K ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:443 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:25 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:43 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
21337 1229K ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       192.168.215.0/24     192.168.215.254
0     0 DROP       udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:17500
1118 60931 DROP       udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:3483
818 78992 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:137:139
1   343 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:67
0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:68
69  4968 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:427
2   200 DROP       icmp --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:4321 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
31820 1815K LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `DROP'
31820 1815K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
38943 2546K PSAD_BLOCK_FORWARD  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.215.3       tcp dpt:80
2790  471K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.215.4       tcp spt:22
89446 4359K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.215.4       state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED udp dpt:54277
122K 7500K ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
123K   11M ACCEPT     all  --  ppp0   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:981 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:500 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 DROP       all  --  ppp0   ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3   120 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `DROP'
3   120 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
7684  919K PSAD_BLOCK_OUTPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:54277
33594 2855K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      ppp0    own.ext.ip       0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3
403 35523 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
1445  121K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      eth0    192.168.215.254      192.168.215.0/24    icmp type 0 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    192.168.215.254      192.168.215.0/24    tcp spt:80 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      eth0    192.168.215.254      192.168.215.0/24    udp spt:161 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
1904  789K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    192.168.215.254      192.168.215.0/24    tcp spt:22 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2780  174K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
16   896 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:43 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
53234   13M ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth0    192.168.215.254      192.168.215.0/24
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4321 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `DROP'
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain PSAD_BLOCK_FORWARD (1 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            121.30.234.78
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       121.30.234.78        0.0.0.0/0
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            118.70.170.83
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       118.70.170.83        0.0.0.0/0

Chain PSAD_BLOCK_INPUT (1 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       121.30.234.78        0.0.0.0/0
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       118.70.170.83        0.0.0.0/0

Chain PSAD_BLOCK_OUTPUT (1 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            121.30.234.78
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            118.70.170.83
```

Comment: `udp` is not a connection oriented protocol.  Since your tables have a default `DROP` policy, I would guess that any `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` connection tracking rules don't work with `udp`.  You likely have to open up outgoing `udp` on source port `54277` to the Internet to allow for return traffic to be sent.  I'm not entirely sure this is accurate, since I didn't read the `conntrack` manual to see if it does anything with `udp`.

Comment: @SeanC: iptables does have logic to allow it to [track UDP conversations](http://www.iptables.info/en/connection-state.html#UDPCONNECTIONS).

Comment: @justin is correct.  Do you have a rule that allows established connections for the `udp` protocol explicitly in your `FORWARD` chain (or a rule for `all` protocols)?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean
I changed the rules to:

iptables -I FORWARD -i ppp0 -p udp --dport 54277 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp -i ppp0 --dport 54277 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.215.4

Still no change, but i get in my firewall log on the router:
Dec 17 22:23:41 fw kernel: [367650.502765] DROPIN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=source.ip DST=dest.external.ip.ppp0 LEN=57 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=36108 DPT=54277 LEN=37

Comment: Can you edit your original post to include your complete ruleset? (`iptables -nvL -t nat; iptables -nvL -t filter` or `iptables-save`)

Comment: Ok, iptables -nvL -t nat; iptables -nvL -t filter added.